# Optimizar tiempo de ejecución de .attr jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, iframe

Hola actualmente tengo estas líneas de código, para restear un iframe de video que aparece en un modal, el detalle esta en que su ejecución es bastante lenta y llega a ser percibida por el usuario, es decir una vez que el usuario le da clic en cerrar, el modal cierra pero el iframe sigue ejecutándose de fondo por unos milisegundos mas.

```
$(".videos-grid .modal .close").click(function() {
    //Cerrar modal
    $(this).parents('.modal').toggleClass('active');
    
    //Buscar iframe
    console.time('search');
    var $frame = $(this).parents('.modal').find('iframe');
    var vidsrc = $frame.attr('src');
    console.timeEnd('search');
    
    //Reset de iframe
    console.time('reset');
    $frame.attr('src','');
    $frame.attr('src', vidsrc);
    console.timeEnd('reset');
});
```

El resultado de los console.time llega hacer hasta de:
[image: resultados de console.time]

Comment: Optimizar *jQuery*, salvo que entres en el propio código de la librería y hagas cambios no se puede. Puedes optimizar como se usa, p.e. si ese iframe tuviera un ID lo vas a cargar más rápido que buscando en el DOM...
En general, muchas de estas cosas las puedes hacer hoy con *Vainilla JS* y funciona infinitamente más rápido...

Comment: Diría que no tienes que esperar hasta que se cierra el modal para buscar el `$frame`, este podrías tenerlo en una variable, de manera que no tengas que buscarlo. Esta variable podría llenarse después de abrir el modal, por ejemplo. Ahorrándote el tiempo de búsqueda, ya solo queda el tiempo de _reset_, que si no te puedes quitar de encima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final omití jQuery de esta porción del código, la ejecución es mas veloz y el usuario no lo percibe tanto.

```
console.time('search');
var $frame = this.closest('.modal').querySelector('iframe');
var vidsrc = $frame.getAttribute('src');
console.timeEnd('search');

console.time('reset');
$frame.setAttribute('src','');
$frame.setAttribute('src', vidsrc);
console.timeEnd('reset');
```

[image: nuevos resultados]